# Draw Google Chart Loading Php Array Using Ajax Inside Native Javascript Method

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, gwt, google-visualization

I'm trying to load php array inside native javascript method of gwt application using ajax and display google chart. But it does not give required output...below are my codes
Server side:

```
    $data = array();
    $data [] = array("Name", "Value");
    $data [] = array("PHP", 78);
    $data [] = array("JAVA", 10);
    $data [] = array("HTML", 120);

    $table = json_encode($data);
    echo $table ;
?>
```

Client side:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Graph</title>
<!-- Load jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="ajax/ajax.nocache.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Load Google JSAPI -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {'packages' : ["corechart"] });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Native javascript method

```
private native void generateGraph()
    /*-{
        $wnd.google.load("visualization", "1", {
            packages : [ 'corechart' ],
            callback : drawChart
        });

        function drawChart() {
                var jsonData = $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost:8080/Ajax/get_json.php",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false
                }).responseText;

                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonData);
                var data = new $wnd.google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(obj);

                var options = {
                    title: 'Graph'
                };

                var chart = new $wnd.google.visualization.LineChart(
                            $wnd.document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                chart.draw(data, options);
            }

    }-*/;
```

thanks for reply!!!

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the developer's console of Chrome or Firefox?  If you navigate to `http://localhost:8080/Ajax/get_json.php` in a browser, do you see the expected JSON string?  It should look like this, given the PHP in your question: `[["Name","Value"],["PHP",78],["JAVA",10],["HTML",120]]`.

Comment: @asgallant get_json.php does give the same result and there are indeed some warnings and errors in developer's console of firefox...but i couldn't figured it out

Comment: Update your question with the error messages.